# popup menu appearing below room even if no space in android

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have a recycler view and each recycler view item has pop up menu
when i open pop up menu for last recycler view item, pop up menu pop up below/ at the end of item and is hidden under screen. 
I hope you get my point.

I have tried changing pop up menu Gravity and also change v7 support pop up menu to widget.pop up menu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried Gravity centre.

Comment: yes, i have tried top, centre gravity but no use.

Answer (score 0):

The docs says:

> A PopupMenu displays a Menu in a modal popup window anchored to a
>   View. The popup will appear below the anchor view if there is room, or
>   above it if there is not. If the IME is visible the popup will not
>   overlap it until it is touched. Touching outside of the popup will
>   dismiss it.

I suppose that there is enough room because you are in a recyclerview and you could scroll down.

Wouldn't you achieve your goal with a dialog? For this you could use `AlertDialog` or `DialogFragment`.

Comment: this issue only occurs when i click on last recycler view item. where screen ends. and popup menu showing below its item.